# hearing the story vs. listening to the story

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, progressive-aspect

Are the following sentences both correct? If so, what's the difference?

> Hearing the story, John started a bit.

> Listening to the story, John started a bit.

Comment: By 'started a bit', do you mean that he was startled by something he heard? If so, _hearing_ would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I meant "be startled." The object of "hearing" was "the story." Would "hearing" still be appropriate?

Comment: Yes, I understand that 'the story' is what he heard, but presumably it was one particular thing in it that was startling. To me, 'listening' seems more to refer to the whole time the story was being told.

Comment: It seems many people reject the "hearing" version in favor of the "listening" one.

Comment: @KateBunting  I could find a few examples of the adverbial use of "Hearing {his, her, the, etc.} story" on GoogleBooks, but most have "after," "upon," or "on" in front.

Answer (score 1):

Hearing the story seems to imply a finished action, whereas listening to it is a process where some point may have been startling for the man.

Comment: I could find a few examples of the adverbial use of "Hearing {his, her, the, etc.} story" on GoogleBooks, but most have "after," "upon," or "on" in front.